# CMP and carry flag

Tags: assembly, msp430, instruction-set

Processor: MSP430 16 bit RISC

Can someone explain the CMP instruction in terms of when the carry flag is actually set below. From the manual it says,

**CMP(.B) src,dst** ..... dst - src

If src is not equal to dst, will the carry flag be set?

```
cmp    r15, r11
jnc    #1234
```

Comment: Depends on which is bigger... if `r11<r15` then `r11-r15<0` hence `CF=1`.

Comment: In this context, is the carry flag only set when the subtraction ( dst - src  ) aka ( r11 - r15 ) results in a negative value?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note, unsigned arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The User's Guide says:

> **Description**
>   The source operand is subtracted from the destination operand. This is made by adding
>   the 1s complement of the source + 1 to the destination. The result affects only the status
>   bits in SR.
>   […]
>   **Status Bits**
>   C: Set if there is a carry from the MSB, reset otherwise

In other words, C is set if there is an unsigned overflow.

This can also be seen in the jump instructions: JC (jump if carry) and JHS (jump if higher or same) are the same instruction, as are JNC (jump if no carry) and JLO (jump if lower).

> **Example**     If R5 ≥ R6 (unsigned), the program continues at Label2.
>
> ```
> CMP R6,R5        ; Is R5 >= R6? Info to C
> JHS Label2       ; Yes, C = 1
> ...              ; No, R5 < R6. Continue
> ```